# ExecuteNonQuery causing Datatype Mismatch Error?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-insert

I'm getting a weird DataType Mismatch error in my code. This only happened after I added command.ExecuteNonQuery to it. Here is the code:

```
private void btn_Next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try {
        connection.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = @"insert into COMPUTERS([TYPE], [COMPANY], [PCNAME], [PROCESSOR], [DRIVE], [RAM], [COMMENT], [YEAR_MADE], [DONOR],[LOCATION], [LOC_SITE], [CONS_DATA], [LABEL], [OLD_ID]) 
                    values (@TYPE, @COMPANY, @PCNAME, @PROCESSOR, @DRIVE, @RAM, @COMMENT, @YEAR_MADE, @DONOR, @LOCATION, @LOC_SITE, @CONS_DATA, @LABEL, @OLD_ID)";

        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TYPE", comboBoxType.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMPANY", comboBoxCompany.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCNAME", txt_PCName);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROCESSOR", txt_Processor);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DRIVE", txt_Drive);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RAM", txt_RAM);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COMMENT", txt_Comment);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@YEAR_MADE", txt_Year);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DONOR", comboBoxDonor.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOCATION", comboBoxLocation.Text);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LOC_SITE", txt_LocSite);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CONS_DATA", txt_ConData);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LABEL", checkBoxLabel.Checked);
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OLD_ID", txt_OldID);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("Καταχώρηση επιτυχής.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error   " + ex);
        }
        connection.Close();

    }
```

I am not sure what the issue is but it's stopping me from inputting data into my Access database.

Comment: What are `txt_PCName` & Co.? Not TextBoxes, right? Have you considered to use `Parameters.Add()` - specifying the data type - instead of `AddWithValue()`: it's not a Stored Procedure, you should make sure, on this side, that the values you pass to the DB match the fields' type (and range).

Comment: BTW, especially when dealing with MS Access, you should not store the Connection object. Ever. Declare it in-place, with a `using` statement. The Command also. If you think that storing the Connection will make *something* faster, it's the exact opposite: you're crippling it, badly.

Comment: @Jimi Hi! Working on replacing all me AddWithValue()s with Parameters.Add(). How do i specify the type when using Parameters.Add()? Also, as a beginner I dont understand what you're suggesting when it comes to the Connection object and the command. Sorry if it's an inconvenience to explain it further

Comment: [Configuring parameters and parameter data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/configuring-parameters-and-parameter-data-types) + related topics, on the left (e.g., `command.Parameters.Add("@TYPE, OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = comboBoxType.Text;`. -- Is, e.g., `txt_PCName`, a TextBox Control?

Comment: About the Connection object: `using (var connection = new OleDbConnection("<Connection string>")) using (var command = new OleDbCommand("<Command Text>") { command.Parameters.Add(...) [...] connection.Open() [...] command.Execute...() }`

Comment: @Jimi so, now after starting to use Parameters.Add() I'm getting a different error and I have no idea what it means https://imgur.com/a/2vZSnAg

Comment: I've already asked you, twice, what are `txt_PCName` & Co. If, e.g.,  `txt_PCName` is a TextBox Control, then you of course have to use its Text Value, not the TextBox object itself: so `[...].Value = txt_PCName.Text` etc.

Comment: @Jimi Yes, they are textboxes, and some of them are comboboxes and one is a checkbox. I would appreciate if you went a bit easier on me, I'm a beginner and maybe things that seem "obvious" to you, are not so obvious to me.Thanks